# Best method to send image and a text from android to wcf service

Tags: android, image, wcf, text, send

I need to send an image and text from android to wcf service, tried with http client with multipart but no luck, kindly suggest.

Comment: Could you add some more details and code showing what you've tried or possible error results / messages?

Comment: i have added the code below

Answer (score 0):

send image using multipartBuilder and send text separately as json via http url connection, the below code for sending image to wcf service is this
Android code

```
public  String postFiless( byte[] imgbyt, String urlString) throws Exception {

            HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpPost post = new HttpPost(urlString);
            MultipartEntityBuilder builder = MultipartEntityBuilder.create();        
            builder.setMode(HttpMultipartMode.BROWSER_COMPATIBLE);         
            byte[] data =  imgbyt;     
            String fileName = String.format("File_%d.jpg",new Date().getTime());
            ByteArrayBody bab = new ByteArrayBody(data, fileName);
            builder.addPart("image", bab);        
            final HttpEntity entity = builder.build();
            post.setEntity(entity );
            HttpResponse response = client.execute(post);     

            Log.e("result code", ""+response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode());

            return getContent(response);

        } 
public static String getContent(HttpResponse response) throws IOException {
            BufferedReader rd = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(response.getEntity().getContent()));
            String body = "";
            String content = "";
            while ((body = rd.readLine()) != null) 
            {
                content += body + "\n";
            }
            return content.trim();
        }
```

WCF CODE TO GET THE IMAGE STREAM SENT FROM ANDROID
Three steps to upload image using Multipart Parser from android to WCF Rest Service

```
//Step 1
//WCF Rest Interface
// Namespace
using System.IO;
[OperationContract]
[WebInvoke(Method = "POST",  ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, UriTemplate = "/UploadImg")]
string UploadImg(Stream fileStream);
Step 2
// WCF Implementation class
// Name spaces
using System.IO;
public string UploadImg(Stream fileStream)        {
            string strRet = string.Empty;
            string strFileName = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory + "Log\\"; // System.Web.Hosting.HostingEnvironment.MapPath("~/Logs/");
            string Path = HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/Photos");// System.Web.Hosting.HostingEnvironment.MapPath("~/Photos/");// HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/Photos/")
            try            {
               MultipartParser parser = new MultipartParser(fileStream);        
                if (parser.Success)  {
                    string fileName = parser.Filename;
                    string contentType = parser.ContentType;
                    byte[] fileContent = parser.FileContents;
                    Encoding encoding = Encoding.UTF8;
                    FileStream fileToupload = new FileStream(Path + "/" + fileName, FileMode.Create);
                    fileToupload.Write(fileContent, 0, fileContent.Length);
                    fileToupload.Close();
                    fileToupload.Dispose();
                    fileStream.Close(); 
                    strRet= fileName;
                }                else                {
                    return "Image Not Uploaded";
                }            }
            catch (Exception ex)           {
                // handle the error
            }
            return strRet;
        }
Step 3
// MultipartParser class
//Namespace
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Text;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
public class MultipartParser    {
         public IDictionary<string, string> Parameters = new Dictionary<string, string>();
         public MultipartParser(Stream stream)        {
            this.Parse(stream, Encoding.UTF8);
        }
        public MultipartParser(Stream stream, Encoding encoding)        {
            this.Parse(stream, encoding);
        }
        public string getcontent(Stream stream, Encoding encoding)        {
            // Read the stream into a byte array
            byte[] data = ToByteArray(stream);
            // Copy to a string for header parsing
            string content = encoding.GetString(data);
            string delimiter = content.Substring(0, content.IndexOf("\r\n"));
            string[] sections = content.Split(new string[] { delimiter }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
            foreach (string s in sections)       {
                Match nameMatch = new Regex(@"(?<=name\=\"")(.*?)(?=\"")").Match(s);
                string name = nameMatch.Value.Trim().ToLower();
                if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(name))        {
                    int startIndex = nameMatch.Index + nameMatch.Length + "\r\n\r\n".Length;    
                }            
}
            string strRet = ""; //Parameters["name"];
            return strRet;
        }
        private void Parse(Stream stream, Encoding encoding)        {
            this.Success = false;
            // Read the stream into a byte array
            byte[] data = ToByteArray(stream);
            // Copy to a string for header parsing
            string content = encoding.GetString(data);
            // The first line should contain the delimiter
            int delimiterEndIndex = content.IndexOf("\r\n");
            if (delimiterEndIndex > -1)    {
                string delimiter = content.Substring(0, content.IndexOf("\r\n"));
                // Look for Content-Type
                Regex re = new Regex(@"(?<=Content\-Type:)(.*?)(?=\r\n\r\n)");
                Match contentTypeMatch = re.Match(content);
                // Look for filename
                re = new Regex(@"(?<=filename\=\"")(.*?)(?=\"")");
                Match filenameMatch = re.Match(content);
                //re = new Regex(@"(?<=name\=\"")(.*?)(?=\"")");
                //Match nameMatch = re.Match(content);
                // Did we find the required values?
                if (contentTypeMatch.Success && filenameMatch.Success)    {
                    // Set properties
                    this.ContentType = contentTypeMatch.Value.Trim();
                    this.Filename = filenameMatch.Value.Trim();
                    // Get the start & end indexes of the file contents
                    int startIndex = contentTypeMatch.Index + contentTypeMatch.Length + "\r\n\r\n".Length;
                    byte[] delimiterBytes = encoding.GetBytes("\r\n" + delimiter);
                    int endIndex = IndexOf(data, delimiterBytes, startIndex);
                    int contentLength = endIndex - startIndex;
                    // Extract the file contents from the byte array
                    byte[] fileData = new byte[contentLength];
                    Buffer.BlockCopy(data, startIndex, fileData, 0, contentLength);
                    this.FileContents = fileData;
                    this.Success = true;                }
            }        }
        private int IndexOf(byte[] searchWithin, byte[] serachFor, int startIndex)       {
            int index = 0;
            int startPos = Array.IndexOf(searchWithin, serachFor[0], startIndex);
            if (startPos != -1)          {
                while ((startPos + index) < searchWithin.Length)             {
                    if (searchWithin[startPos + index] == serachFor[index])                   {
                        index++;
                        if (index == serachFor.Length)                        {
                            return startPos;
                        }
                    }    else      {
                        startPos = Array.IndexOf<byte>(searchWithin, serachFor[0], startPos + index);
                        if (startPos == -1)      {
                           return -1;
                        }
                        index = 0;
                    }
                }
            }
            return -1;
        }
        private byte[] ToByteArray(Stream stream)        {
            byte[] buffer = new byte[32768];
            using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())           {
                while (true)       {
                    int read = stream.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
                    if (read <= 0)
                        return ms.ToArray();
                    ms.Write(buffer, 0, read);
                }
            }
        }
        public bool Success        {
            get;
            private set;
        }
        public string ContentType        {
            get;
            private set;
        }
        public string Filename        {
            get;
            private set;
        }
        public byte[] FileContents        {
            get;
            private set;
        }
        public string Imgname        {
            get;
            private set;
        }    }
// End of Wcf rest Service Code
```